# PHP: How to prevent form fields from being pre-filled if a user hits a browser back button?

Tags: php, html, forms, browser

In my HTML form, after a user hits submit, the PHP code will navigate a user to a different page via `header("Location: ...")`.

Now if a user hits the browser back button and goes back to the form, some of the fields remain filled in. This is not a desired effect as it mucks up data in subsequently submitted forms.

If a user hits refresh on the page, the normal behaviour is exhibited and the form is returned in a blank state. So there is something subtly different between the back button to a page and a refresh on the same page.

How can i get the form to remain cleared when a user hits the back button? Is there something that needs to be included in the PHP script such as `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");`?

In .NET MVC, this issue seems to be rectified when decorating an action with `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]`. Is there something equivalent to this in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Hi there I just wanted to share the solution that have came up for your problem.

HTML FORM:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" class="formName">
  <input type="text" name="text1" class="formField"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
</form>
```

JS Script:

```
window.onload = function() {
  let form = document.querySelector("form.formName");
  let formField = form.querySelectorAll('.formField');

  for (var i = formField.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    formField[i].value = '';
  }
}
```

I created a JS script that is designed to reset the ".formField" fields from the ".formName" form.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Another easier method would be to use `$("form input").val("")`; however i want to try and understand why this is occuring and not just make a hack fix for it

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" class="formName" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="text1" class="formField"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
</form>
```